# How to create a tabbar that sync with a widget scroll in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, nestedscrollview

Basically what I want to accomplish here is to have a horizontal list of categories(could be TabBar) and a vertical list of the categories with items list in each category.

And when you click on a category it should scroll to a position in the vertical list of categories.
And when you scroll the vertical list, the active category at the top should also update the current active category.

I've seen this function in the FoodPanda app but I am not able to replicate it.

Any suggestions on how can I accomplish this functionality?

Here's the screenshot of the UI.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_list_tabview
code snippet

```
body: ScrollableListTabView(
        tabHeight: 48,
        bodyAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        tabAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
        tabAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        tabs: [
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(
                  label: Text('Vegetables'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                  showIconOnList: false),
              body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Vegetables element $index'),
                ),
              )),
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(label: Text('Fruits'), icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
              body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_list_tabview/scrollable_list_tabview.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter ScrollableListTabView Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ScrollableListTabView(
        tabHeight: 48,
        bodyAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        tabAnimationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
        tabAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        tabs: [
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(
                  label: Text('Vegetables'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                  showIconOnList: false),
              body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Vegetables element $index'),
                ),
              )),
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(label: Text('Fruits'), icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
              body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Fruits element $index'),
                ),
              )),
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(label: Text('Meat'), icon: Icon(Icons.group)),
              body: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                  leading: Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Meat element $index'),
                ),
              )),
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(
                  label: Text('Herbs&Spices'), icon: Icon(Icons.subject)),
              body: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
                  child: Center(child: Text('Herbs&Spices element $index')),
                ),
              )),
          ScrollableListTab(
              tab: ListTab(
                  label: Text('Egg'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.subject),
                  showIconOnList: true),
              body: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2),
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) => Card(
                  child: Center(child: Text('Egg element $index')),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What an angel! I'll try this out!

Comment: @JaysonObado, Glad to help. please upvote or mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Definitely @chunhunghan! I never found this package. I've been searching for weeks! And this works perfectly!

Comment: did you solved ur issue? Im trying to do as foodpanda but can't implement the list please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780622/flutter-return-list-of-categorise-tabs-and-items?noredirect=1#comment123345765_69780622

Answer (score 3):

I have tried several methods but this seems to be best for me.

**Packages:**

```yaml
scroll_to_index: ^2.0.0 
rect_getter: ^1.0.0
```

Usage of `rect_getter` is inspired by: https://gist.github.com/debuggerx01/49f108d68ed903458e9478b4f0c186f4

**Code** (Food Panda Clone):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';
import 'package:food_panda_sticky_header/colors.dart';
import 'package:food_panda_sticky_header/example_data.dart';
import 'package:food_panda_sticky_header/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:rect_getter/rect_getter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isCollapsed = false;
  late AutoScrollController scrollController;
  late TabController tabController;

  final double expandedHeight = 500.0;
  final PageData data = ExampleData.data;
  final double collapsedHeight = kToolbarHeight;

  final listViewKey = RectGetter.createGlobalKey();
  Map<int, dynamic> itemKeys = {};

  // prevent animate when press on tab bar
  bool pauseRectGetterIndex = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: data.categories.length, vsync: this);
    scrollController = AutoScrollController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<int> getVisibleItemsIndex() {
    Rect? rect = RectGetter.getRectFromKey(listViewKey);
    List<int> items = [];
    if (rect == null) return items;
    itemKeys.forEach((index, key) {
      Rect? itemRect = RectGetter.getRectFromKey(key);
      if (itemRect == null) return;
      if (itemRect.top > rect.bottom) return;
      if (itemRect.bottom < rect.top) return;
      items.add(index);
    });
    return items;
  }

  void onCollapsed(bool value) {
    if (this.isCollapsed == value) return;
    setState(() => this.isCollapsed = value);
  }

  bool onScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (pauseRectGetterIndex) return false;
    int lastTabIndex = tabController.length - 1;
    List<int> visibleItems = getVisibleItemsIndex();

    bool reachLastTabIndex = visibleItems.length <= 2 && visibleItems.last == lastTabIndex;
    if (reachLastTabIndex) {
      tabController.animateTo(lastTabIndex);
    } else {
      int sumIndex = visibleItems.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
      int middleIndex = sumIndex ~/ visibleItems.length;
      if (tabController.index != middleIndex) tabController.animateTo(middleIndex);
    }

    return false;
  }

  void animateAndScrollTo(int index) {
    pauseRectGetterIndex = true;
    tabController.animateTo(index);
    scrollController
        .scrollToIndex(index, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin)
        .then((value) => pauseRectGetterIndex = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: scheme.background,
      body: RectGetter(
        key: listViewKey,
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
          child: buildSliverScrollView(),
          onNotification: onScrollNotification,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSliverScrollView() {
    return CustomScrollView(
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: scrollController,
      slivers: [
        buildAppBar(),
        buildBody(),
      ],
    );
  }

  SliverAppBar buildAppBar() {
    return FAppBar(
      data: data,
      context: context,
      scrollController: scrollController,
      expandedHeight: expandedHeight,
      collapsedHeight: collapsedHeight,
      isCollapsed: isCollapsed,
      onCollapsed: onCollapsed,
      tabController: tabController,
      onTap: (index) => animateAndScrollTo(index),
    );
  }

  SliverList buildBody() {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        List.generate(data.categories.length, (index) {
          itemKeys[index] = RectGetter.createGlobalKey();
          return buildCategoryItem(index);
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildCategoryItem(int index) {
    Category category = data.categories[index];
    return RectGetter(
      key: itemKeys[index],
      child: AutoScrollTag(
        key: ValueKey(index),
        index: index,
        controller: scrollController,
        child: CategorySection(category: category),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Demo**:
https://github.com/theacheng/food_panda_sticky_header/pull/4

Comment: Yeah, I'm having scrolling issues with the https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_list_tabview I'm gonna try your solution. Thanks!